# dependency for 'forEach' in junit

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I have the following code that uses forEach. While running the junit tests for the function it belongs to, it fails. But, when the program is run and executed, this loop functions perfectly. 
I don't know if I need any dependencies or not.

```
getname() {
JSONArray arrays = "<array>";
arrays.forEach(o -> {
                    if (o instanceof JSONObject) {
                        if (((JSONObject) o).get("something").equals(name)) {
                            code= ((JSONObject) o).get("code");
                        }
                    }
                });
}
```

This is my test case

```
@Test
    public void testMethod()  {
        String code = serviceClass.getname();
    }
}
```

the call method is the function that has the above mentioned code.

The above code fails with `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json.JSONArray.forEach` at the `array.forEach(o -> {` line

I have tried many dependencies, but as per my knowledge goes, Collections is the only dependency that is needed. 
So whats going wrong?

Comment: It might help to see the error messages you see.

Comment: please put the snippet of class/method under test. and your test code

Comment: @duffymo - the error code is as mentioned above

Comment: JSONArray is not a stream.  You can only execute forEach on a stream.  This sentence confuses me: "While running the junit tests for the function it belongs to, it fails. But, when the program is run and executed, this loop functions perfectly."

Comment: Your pom would also be nice to be included as it may shed light